# Search for 2nd occurrence of a string in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How to search for 2nd occurrence of a string in another string in VBA ?

For example , in below given string,the word "test" occurs twice.

> this is a **test** to **test**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply do the search twice

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim DataString As String
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim i As Long

    DataString = "this is a test to test"
    SearchString = "test"

    i = InStr(1, DataString, SearchString, vbTextCompare)
    i = InStr(i + 1, DataString, SearchString, vbTextCompare)

    Debug.Print "Second occurance starts at position " & i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

*update*
To just find the last occurrence then just

```
MsgBox InStrRev("this is a test to test", "test")
```

*initial answer which handled less than 2 occurrences*

A little ungainly but handles 1 or 0 occurences

```
Dim strIn As String
Dim strOut As String
Dim lngPos As Long
Dim lngPos2 As Long

strIn = "test"
strOut = "this is a test to test"

lngPos = InStr(strOut, strIn)

If lngPos > 0 Then
    lngPos2 = InStr(lngPos + 1, strOut, strIn)
    If lngPos2 > 0 Then MsgBox strIn & " at " & lngPos2
Else
    MsgBox "No " & strIn
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

To find the 2nd occurrence of a string, use the InStr function twice.  Note that the substring for which you search could be a repeating character sequence like "dd".  In this case you have to determine if you want to return 5 or 6 as the result of searching for "bb" in "abcdddd".  That is, do you want to start searching for the second occurrence of "dd" at at the end of the first occurrence or at the second character of the first occurrence?

```
Private Sub ExampleFind2ndOccurrence()
    Dim intFirst As Integer, intSecond As Integer
    Dim searchThisString As String: searchThisString = "abcdddddefg"
    Dim forThisSubString As String: forThisSubString = "dd"

    ' Find the first occurrence of forThisSubString
    intFirst = InStr(1, searchThisString, forThisSubString, vbTextCompare)

    ' Find the second occurrence of forThisSubString
    intSecond = InStr(1, Mid(searchThisString, intFirst + 1), forThisSubString, vbTextCompare)
    If intSecond > 0 Then intSecond = intFirst + intSecond
    Debug.Print "2nd occurrence occurs at character position "; intSecond

    ' Alternate method to find second occurrence of forThisSubString in the
    ' case where there can be no overlap
    intSecond = InStr(1, Mid(searchThisString, intFirst + Len(forThisSubString)), forThisSubString, vbTextCompare)
    If intSecond > 0 Then intSecond = intFirst + Len(forThisSubString) - 1 + intSecond
    Debug.Print "Prohibbitting overlap, 2nd occurrence occurs at character position "; intSecond
End Sub
```

Find the Nth occurrence of a substring:

```
Public Function InStr2(ByVal IntStartPosition As Variant _
                       , ByVal Str As String _
                       , ByVal SubStr As String _
                       , Optional IntCompareMethod As Integer = vbTextCompare _
                       , Optional IntOccurrence As Integer = 1 _
                       , Optional BlnOverlapOK As Boolean = False)
' Find the IntOccurrence instance of SubStr in Str
' Parameters:
    ' IntStartPosition (Integer): the character position at which to start searching.
                                 ' (See docs for InStr)
    ' Str (String): the string to search.  (See docs for InStr)
    ' SubStr (String): the substring to find in Str.  (See docs for InStr)
    ' IntCompareMethod (integer): a VBA compare enumeration value.  (See docs for InStr)
    ' IntOccurrence (integer): The number of instances of SubStr for which to search
    ' BlnOverlapOK (boolean): Is it okay for the Nth occurence of SubStr to overlap the
                              ' N-1 occurrence?
' Returns the location of the occurence of the IntOccurrence instance of SubStr in Str
    Dim s As String
    Dim intCharPos As Integer
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim intStart As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Initialize
    If IsMissing(IntStartPosition) Then IntStartPosition = 1
    intStart = IntStartPosition
    Str = Mid(Str, intStart)

    intCharPos = 1
    cnt = 0
    i = 1
    Do While intCharPos <= Len(Str) And cnt < IntOccurrence
        s = Mid(Str, intCharPos)
        i = InStr(1, s, SubStr, IntCompareMethod)
        If i = 0 Or i = Null Then
            InStr2 = i
            Exit Function
        End If
        cnt = cnt + 1
        If BlnOverlapOK Or Len(SubStr) = 1 Or cnt = IntOccurrence Then
            intCharPos = intCharPos + i
        Else
            intCharPos = intCharPos + i + Len(SubStr) - 1
        End If
    Loop
    InStr2 = intCharPos - 1

End Function
```

Example of finding nth occurrence of substring:

```
Private Sub InStr2Example()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim searchThisString As String: searchThisString = "abcddddddd"
                                                       '1234567890
    Dim forThisSubString As String: forThisSubString = "dd"
    i = InStr2(1, searchThisString, forThisSubString, vbTextCompare, 3, True)
    Debug.Print "3rd occurrence occurs at character position "; i
    i = InStr2(1, searchThisString, forThisSubString, vbTextCompare, 3, False)
    Debug.Print "Prohibbitting overlap, 3rd occurrence occurs at character position "; i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to find where the first occurrence starts and then offset the search range accordingly.

A nested `Mid`/`InStr` function will do the trick:

```
Dim x As String, fVal As String

x = "test this is a test"
fVal = "test"

y = Mid$(Mid$(x, InStr(x, fVal) + Len(fVal)), InStr(Mid$(x, InStr(x, fVal) + Len(fVal)), fVal))

Debug.Print y
```

Answer (score 1):

A flexible function to find *any* occurrence using `Split()` could be:

```
Function GetPosition(ByVal FullText As String, ByVal SearchString As String, ByVal occurrence As Long, Optional ByVal CaseSensitive As Boolean = False) As Long
'Purpose: get start position of a given search occurrence within fulltext
'[0]case sensitive? (case insensitive by default)
    If Not CaseSensitive Then
        FullText = LCase(FullText): SearchString = LCase(SearchString)
    End If
'[1]split fulltext into substrings
    Dim part: part = Split(FullText, SearchString)  ' split fulltext
    If occurrence < 1 Then Exit Function            ' accept only positive occurrencies
    If occurrence > UBound(part) Then Exit Function ' refuse too high occurrencies
'[2]add substrings plus searchstring lengths
    Dim i As Long, n As Long                        ' counters
    For i = 0 To occurrence - 1
        n = n + Len(part(i))                        ' add part lengths
    Next
    n = n + (occurrence - 1) * Len(SearchString) + 1
'[3]return search position of wanted occurrence
    GetPosition = n
End Function
```

**Example call**

```
Sub Test()
Dim s As String: s = "this is a test to test to test"  ' (three occurrencies of "test")
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 4
    Debug.Print "Occurrence " & i, "starts at position " & GetPosition(s, "tEst", i)
Next
End Sub
```