# Finding the fifth slash "/"

Tags: excel, vba, find

https://www.walmart.com/cp/the-curl-shop/5859906

```
Function FindR()

Dim sFindWhat As String
Dim sInputString As String

Dim N As Integer
Dim J As Integer
Dim K As Integer

sFindWhat = "/"
sInputString = Range("A1").Value



Debug.Print sInputString
Application.Volatile
FindR = 0

For J = 1 To N

FindR = InStr(FindR + 1, sInputString, sFindWhat)
K = FindR
If FindR = 0 Then Exit For
Range("A1").Value = K
Debug.Print K
Next
End Function
```

I need to find the position of the 5th slash "/" in my link by vba. As i dont know much about Macro kindly need help.

Comment: Are you aware of the `InStrRev` function? It might be a better alternative.

Comment: Are you just trying to get that number at the end?

Comment: yes absolutely I need the position number alone in all my different Links

Comment: The position of the *last* `/` in the string can be found with: `InStrRev(sInputString,"/")`

Comment: yes I came to know about InstrRev by googling it can find the Specific character from the right but in my case the Link has more than ten slashes i need to find specifically the fifth slash position please help and Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at the "Nth occurrence" answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62472136/7446760

Comment: adding another sample link to the thread https://www.walmart.com/browse/beauty/shampoo/1085666_3147628_5752434

Comment: You might also want to review the `Split` function, which breaks a string down into an array using a separator. This allows you to take specific parts of the string using the index.

Comment: I cant able to understand the  "Nth occurrence" answer here: stackoverflow.com/a/62472136/7446760

Comment: Will this work : `=LEN(A1)-LEN(TEXTAFTER(A1,"/",5))` ?

Comment: @NewtonKapildev are you specifically looking for a vba code? I found the above formula is working for your requirement.

Comment: This seems like a classic [XY Problem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjbtsWT3_T9AhUBjokEHZLeCM8QFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fxyproblem.info%2F&usg=AOvVaw0o8R0CPtO_7hy4hFQgvAC1). Why don't you explain what you are really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was trying to find fourth and fifth slash position and then check the string in between fourth and fifth is number or string if it was a number(integer) I no need to delete it but if it is a string I need to delete it from the Link and to generate new link by deleting the String inside the 4th and 5th slash. Please Anyone help on this.   Now I got the solution to get the position of 4th and fifth slash and assigned a variant to store that value. Now I need to Check the stored value is integer or not if it was string i need to delete it from my full link.

Comment: Thanks to Everyone I got the code.

Comment: You can also use a worksheet formula: `=LET(x,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),5),
chars,AND(ISERR(- MID(x,SEQUENCE(LEN(x)),1))),
IF(chars,TEXTBEFORE(A1,"/",4) & "/" & TEXTAFTER(A1,"/",5),A1))`

Answer (score 2):

I would just use `Split` instead of getting the "index of the 5th slash" if you just want the number at the end. It's easier.

This will show you how to split it.

```
Sub test()
  Dim s As String
  Dim v As Variant
  
  s = "https://www.walmart.com/cp/the-curl-shop/5859906"
  v = Split(s, "/")
  Debug.Print v(UBound(v))
End Sub
```

If you want to strip out the last number:

```
Debug.Print Replace(s, v(UBound(v)), "")
```

If you are trying to get `the-curl-shop` then:

```
Debug.Print v(4)
```

Comment: i need excatly the position of the 5th slash alone not the number

Comment: Thanks for your above code still i need help

Comment: its not a homework i was trying to find fourth and fifth slash position and then check the string in between fourth and fifth is number or string if it was number i dont delete it if it is a string i need to delete it from the Link and to generate new link by deleting the String inside the 4th and 5th slash. Please Anyone guide me

Comment: If it is just about getting the last part, I think `Mid(s, InStrRev(s, "/") + 1)` is better, it's more efficient and shorter. If it is about getting some of the middle parts, I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have described what you actually want in one of the comments to braXs answer, maybe this will do what you want:

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim s As String
    Dim s2 As String

    s = "asdf/2345/asfd/asdf/todel/adsf/asfd/"
    s2 = "asdf/2345/asfd/asdf/12345/adsf/asfd/"

    Debug.Print Delete5thPartIfNotNumeric(s)
    Debug.Print Delete5thPartIfNotNumeric(s2)
End Sub

Function Delete5thPartIfNotNumeric(ByVal str As String)
    Dim parts As Variant

    Delete5thPartIfNotNumeric = str
    parts = Split(str, "/")
    If UBound(parts) < 4 Then Exit Function

    If Not IsNumeric(Replace(parts(4), " ", "")) Then
        parts(4) = ""
        Delete5thPartIfNotNumeric = Replace(Join(parts, "/"), "//", "/", , 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Fantastic! its working like a pro. Thanks to Everyone!

Comment: I was trying to find fourth and fifth slash position and then check the string in between fourth and fifth is number or string if it was a number(integer) I no need to delete it but if it is a string I need to delete it from the Link and to generate new link by deleting the String inside the 4th and 5th slash. Please Anyone help on this.

Comment: @NewtonKapildev I don't understand your second comment as in the first comment you say this already works? Just pass the link to the function I provided and it will return your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test()
Dim sFindWhat As String
Dim sInputString As String
Dim targetNumber As String
Dim targetPosition As Long

sInputString = "https://www.walmart.com/cp/the-curl-shop/5859906"

'if you need just the final NUMBER use SPLIT
targetNumber = Split(sInputString, "/")(UBound(Split(sInputString, "/")))
Debug.Print targetNumber

'if you need the POSITION of last / use InStrRev
targetPosition = InStrRev(sInputString, "/")
Debug.Print targetPosition

End Sub
```

Output

[image]

> [Split
> function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function)
>
> [InStrRev
> function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instrrev-function)

***UPDATED**: Looks like OP needs always the fifth slash, so use a UDF to get it looping. You can call the UDF on macros or even a cell:

```
Sub test()
Dim Test1 As String
Dim Test2 As String

Test1 = "https://www.walmart.com/cp/the-curl-shop/5859906"
Test2 = "https://www.walmart.com/browse/beauty/shampoo/1085666_3147628_5752434"


Debug.Print Test1, GET_FIFTH_SLASH(Test1)
Debug.Print Test2, GET_FIFTH_SLASH(Test2)

End Sub

Public Function GET_FIFTH_SLASH(ByVal vString As String) As Long
Dim i As Long
GET_FIFTH_SLASH = 0

'first loop gets position of first /
'second loop, starting at position of first /, will get position of second /
'and so on...
For i = 1 To 5 Step 1
    GET_FIFTH_SLASH = InStr(GET_FIFTH_SLASH + 1, vString, "/")
Next i


End Function
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your code. But it works for the specific Link but it returns wrong while running with another link https://www.walmart.com/browse/beauty/shampoo/1085666_3147628_5752434. Still Need help

Comment: The problem here is that it's not always between the 4th and 5th like your question states. This URL has more slashes in it than the first one.

Comment: @NewtonKapildev please, check the update in the answer

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ModifyUrl()

    Dim url1 As String, url2 As String, regex, m, s As String
    url1 = "https://www.walmart.com/cp/abcdefh/5859906"
    
    ' capture between 4th and 5th /
    Const P = "(https://.*/.*/)(.*)/(.*)"
    
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = P ' pattern
        
        If .test(url1) Then
            Set m = .Execute(url1)
            ' between 4th and 5th /
            s = m(0).submatches(1)
        
            ' remove middle $2 if not numeric
            If Not IsNumeric(s) Then
                 url2 = .Replace(url1, "$1" & "$3")
            Else
                 url2 = url1
            End If
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox url1 & vbLf & url2, vbInformation, s

End Sub
```